# How to create a RealTime ApexChart with vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, apexcharts

I am trying to follow the vue documentation on ApexCharts website.
https://apexcharts.com/vue-chart-demos/line-charts/realtime/

and the way they structured the component isn't practical. and seem like they have some missing methods in the example.

I wish to create a chart as in the example above that fetches data every second (1 second worth data)

```js
<template>
        <VueApexCharts
            type="line"
            height="350"
            width="100%"
            :options="chartOptions"
            :series="series"
            ref="chart"
        />
</template>

<script>
import { ref } from "vue";
import VueApexCharts from "vue3-apexcharts";
import { useStore } from "vuex";

export default {
    name: "ChartApex",
    components: { VueApexCharts },
    props: ["session"],
    setup(/* props */) {
        let store = useStore();
        let chartStream = undefined;
        let series = [
            {
                name: "data1",
                data: ref([]),
            },
            {
                name: "data2",
                data: [],
            },
        ];

        let chartOptions = {
            chart: {
                // id: "realtime",
                width: "100%",
                height: 350,
                type: "line",
                animations: {
                    enabled: true,
                    easing: "linear",
                    dynamicAnimation: {
                        speed: 1000,
                    },
                },
                toolbar: {
                    show: true,
                },
                zoom: {
                    enabled: true,
                },
            },
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true,
            },
            stroke: {
                curve: "straight",
            },
            title: {
                text: "Chart",
                align: "left",
            },
            grid: {
                row: {
                    colors: ["#f3f3f3", "transparent"],
                    opacity: 0.5,
                },
            },
            xaxis: {
                type: "numeric",
                show: true,
                range: 3,
            },
            yaxis: {
                min: -32768,
                show: true,
                max: 32768,
            },
        };

        return {
            chartOptions,
            series,
            store,
            chartStream,
        };
    },

    watch: {
        "session.device.isDataStream"(newVal) {
            if (newVal) this.startStream();
            else this.endStream();
        },
    },
    methods: {
        startStream() {
            console.log("starting chart stream");
            this.chartStream = setInterval(() => {
                // Push data
                this.series[0].data.value.push(
                    ...this.store.state.session.samples[0].at(-1)
                );
            }, 1000);
        },
        endStream() {
            console.log("end chart srtrem");
            clearInterval(this.chartStream);
        },
    },
};
</script>
```

- I wish to display a range of 10 seconds on the X-axis (as in the example above).
- When getting a new 1 second worth data: i would like my chart to show extra data and move one second ahead (x-axis) so it always remain as 10 seconds in total.
- I am fetching data from my store which keeps updating in chunks. unfortunatly it stacks all in one chart that doesn't move. I wish to display one chunk every second.
- I would prefer linking my data directly to the store variable. I am not doing this because i would need to use `computed` method, and i think it's less efficient (is it?)
- the `store.state.samples[0]` is an array of chunks with around 1 second worth of data in each, structured as apex-charts use: `[ts, sample]` - looks like this:

```
// samples[0]
[
    // Chunk 1 of almost a second
    // [0] => 
    [
        [ // sample
            8.75,
            0
        ],
        [ // sample
            17.5,
            -1
        ],
        [ // etc
            26.25,
            -2
        ],
        [
            35,
            -3
        ],...
        
    ],
    [ // Chunk 2 of almost a second.
        [
            958.6875,
            -12747
        ],
        [
            962.375,
            -12808
        ],
        [
            966.0625,
            -12789
        ],...
    ]
]
```

so that basically i push a chunk worth a second to my chart (..every second)

A lot recommend on apex-charts as a go-to charts library for vue, but seems they lack of proper documentation.

-

Answer (score 0):

Here is link to the [source code of the sample](https://github.com/apexcharts/apexcharts.js/blob/ff248b4a38ee21e993e38ef9a3e1318e59a6ea32/samples/vue/line/realtime.html). Check there how it was built.

To show the range of 10 seconds use the `xaxis.range` setting:

```
 const TICKINTERVAL = 1000;
 const XAXISRANGE = 10000;
 const ARRAYLENGTH = XAXISRANGE / TICKINTERVAL + 1;

  xaxis: {
            type: 'datetime',
            range: XAXISRANGE,
            position: 'bottom',
```

To move the X-Axis you should slice you data array, like the `resetData()` function does:

```
function resetData(){
  data = data.slice(data.length - 10, data.length);
}
```

I did it with my `ARRAYLENGTH` constant

```
data.push(...new Data...);
if (data.length > ARRAYLENGTH) data = data.slice(-ARRAYLENGTH);
```